# waiting for 6-edge-chat.facebook.com forever on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, facebook, facebook-chat

For about a couple of days now, I cannot browse `facebook.com` properly anymore on Chrome.

The main page is displayed, then it stalls while `waiting for 6-edge-chat.facebook.com` forever. It seems related to the chat. However, when I try with Firefox, I don't get that issue. I am on Windows 10.

I have tried to `restore settings to their original defaults on Chrome`, but to not avail. Any ideas/suggestions to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue disappeared by itself today. Maybe the solution is to be patient (a cache needs to expire on the PC or on the net, who knows?)